# Выполнение функции после загрузки части страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Требуется после загрузки части страницы через ajax, выполнить скрипт из загружаемой страницы.
Делаю так

```
<script language="jscript">
$(document).ready(function(){
form_edit_x_type_calc();
});
</script>
```

Это в конце загружаемой страницы.
Функция делает некие операции с `<select … onChange="form_edit_x_type_calc();" >`, по самому select все работает, но при старте функция не выполняется.

```
function form_edit_x_type_calc(){

    var s=document.form_edit_usel.x_type_calc;    

    if(s.value == 0){
        document.form_edit_usel.x_imei.setAttribute('maxlength', 15);
        document.form_edit_usel.x_type_sch.disabled=false;
        document.form_edit_usel.x_type_canal.disabled=false;
        document.form_edit_usel.x_kod.disabled=false;
        document.form_edit_usel.x_nt.disabled=false;
        document.form_edit_usel.x_speed.disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("id_Font_namber_usel").innerHTML="******";

    }

    if (s.value == 1){

        document.form_edit_usel.x_imei.setAttribute('maxlength', 6);
        document.form_edit_usel.x_type_sch.disabled=true;
        document.form_edit_usel.x_type_canal.disabled=true;
        document.form_edit_usel.x_kod.disabled=true;
        document.form_edit_usel.x_nt.disabled=true;
        document.form_edit_usel.x_speed.disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("id_Font_namber_usel").innerHTML="******";


    }


}
```

Comment: Где у вас определена функция `form_edit_x_type_calc`? Я бы предположил что на `ready` она ещё недоступна. В консоли что-нибудь есть? И уберите `language="jscript"` - лишнее это и в данном случае ещё и невалидное. И ещё, если это перед закрытием `body`, то `ready` в принципе и не требуется.

Comment: функция определяется в `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/edit_usel.js"></script>`  это находится выше по коду. Это все после `body`

Comment: Ну в принципе не вижу причин по которым она бы не должна была тогда работать. Посмотрите консоль. Не исключена вероятность что и сама `form_edit_x_type_calc` работает не так как надо. Приведите её код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот поставьте [точку останова](https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome) перед `if(s.value == 0){` и посмотрите значение `s.value`. Есть подозрение что он не `0` и не `1` или вообще `s` не определено. Поэтому ничего и не происходит.

Если вам какое-то из значение нужно по умолчанию, например `0`, то сделайте просто ветку `else`:

```
if(s.value == 1) { ... }
else { ... }
```

Comment: да все верно, не верный параметр в `s.value` спс